# How to use an animated .GIF as a desktop picture for Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion

As the title says.

I have an animated GIF that I would like to set as a desktop picture for my Mac running Mountain Lion 10.8.4

Thanks for the responces

Answer (score 1):

You can give a try a [deskfun](http://www.furrysoft.de/?page=deskfun), you can place gif images as background using it,from their website this tool can be used too :

```
Place pictures on the desktop or let them float above normal windows.
Accepts any picture format supported by the OS.
Supports pictures with transparency.
Supports animated GIFs.
Several different frames available.
Manage multiple arrangements of pictures
```

Hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

I found [this link](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/60657/how-to-set-animated-gif-as-a-wallpaper) on apple Stack Exchange site. The answer to that question says there is an app that sets screensavers as wallpapers.

Comment: Do you have the same thing for mountain lion? I tried that, and it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I made a tiny screensaver that can play GIF's and can run in background. It is free and I upload the source code to Github so that every one can look how it is done and participate in further development. 
I only test the screensaver under 10.9.5 so I don't know if has issues on newer OSX releases(?). 
Here is the Github link: https://github.com/Stino/AnimatedGif 
And here a ZIP of the compiled screensaver: https://github.com/Stino/AnimatedGif/blob/master/Release/AnimatedGif.saver.zip

Greetings Stino